# Are "strongly finite dimensional" homotopy invariant sheaves with transfers (locally) constant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, motives, rigidity

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $S$ be a homotopy invariant $\mathbb{Q}$-linear sheaf with transfers in the sense of Voevodsky–Suslin, and assume that the dimension of $S(U)$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) is bounded for a constant $c$ if $U$ is a smooth (connected) $k$-variety. Is it known that $S$ is constant?

I probably have a somewhat clumsy proof of this fact using Suslin rigidity-type arguments; yet I wonder which facts related to this one are already known. Moreover, I am actually interested in the extension of $S$ to pro-smooth (say, affine) $k$-schemes; and my finite dimensionality assumption corresponds to the finite dimensionality of $S(\operatorname{Spec} K)$, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field extension of $k$ of infinite transcendence degree. Consequently, I would also like to know which statements should I cite to deal with "colimit extensions" of this sort; is this section 8.13 of EGA 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have proved this statement as Lemma 5.1.3 at [Bondarko and Sosnilo - On Chow-weight homology of geometric motives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340849991_On_Chow-weight_homology_of_geometric_motives).  Comments are very welcome!

Comment: Why not on the arXiv, or at least your web-page?  (I always find the maybe-available-maybe-not interface of ResearchGate confusing and slightly scammy seeming.)

Comment: I should create my webpage, but I didn't find time to do this yet.(: As about arxiv: there is an alternative version of our paper there. Neither of the versions is currently "strictly better" than another one; thus I would prefer to keep them at distinct places. Maybe, I will merge the versions eventually.

Comment: I noticed on the arXiv that there is a paper with different authors: [Bondarko and Zumallagov - On Chow-weight homology of motivic complexes and its relation to motivic homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09353).  Is that the one to which you [refer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364236/are-strongly-finite-dimensional-homotopy-invariant-sheaves-with-transfers-loc/364578#comment920139_364578)?

Comment: No; this is the next paper on the subject; it is very much different from both versions of the text that I refer above (the other one is https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6354). My new co-author is Kumallagov.:)

Comment: Oops, sorry for misspelling Kumallagov's name!